# Return true if the array contains duplicate elements (which need not be adjacent)

Tags: java, arrays

When I execute this, even if there are no duplicates, it displays true. Basically, it displays true for every array that I put in. I have no idea why it's showing me that. I would appreciate some help in this problem! Thanks!

```
public static boolean Duplicate()
{
 int [] duplicateArray = new int[5];
 System.out.print("Enter your array numbers:");
 System.out.println();
 for(int i = 0; i < duplicateArray.length; i++)
 {
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 duplicateArray[i] = in.nextInt();
 }
 boolean same = false;
 for(int i = 0; i < duplicateArray.length-1; i++)
 {
  for(int j = 0; j < duplicateArray.length; j++)
  {
  
   if(i==j)
   {
    same = true;
   }
  }
 }
 return same;
}
```

Comment: This is because the initialised values in the array are  0.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. I put in "i+1" for j and now it displays false everytime.

Comment: you compare the wrong thing :D if (i==j) should be if (duplicateArray[i] == duplicteArray[j]). Are you new to programming? you should check how to debug code to see how your code run

Comment: yeah I am kind of new. It's just my first time learning coding. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing array offsets, not the values at those offsets.

This

```
if(i==j)
```

should be

```
if(duplicateArray[i]== duplicateArray[j])
```

That said, your algorithm is pretty inefficient. At the least, you should break the loop once a duplicate is detected. The easiest way to do that is to immediately `return true` (then you don't need your `same` variable.

A more efficient approach would be to sort the array, and just compare each index with the previous one. That gives you a worst case complexity of O(n log n) instead of O(n^2).

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now! How stupid was I to not realize that this whole time.

Comment: @Thatnotsosmartgeek not at all stupid. Stuff like this happens all the time to the most experienced of us

Answer (score 0):

So, there is in the code

```
if (i==j) {
   same = true;
}
```

You are comparing induces, not value. You have to skip comparing values at the same index, like this:

```
if (i==j) {
   continue;
}

if (duplicateArray[i] == duplicateArray[j]) {
    same = true;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, the problem in your code is that you compare the indices (`i and j`) rather than the values (`duplicateArray[i] and duplicateArray[j]`).

Therefore, changing

```
if (i == j)
```

to

```
if (duplicateArray[i] == duplicateArray[j])
```

should fix your problem.

However, to improve your solution (which is currently an `O(n^2)` algorithm since you have two nested loops that traverse the entire array), here are several methods:

1. Return `true` when finding two equal elements:

Basically, rather than

```
same = true;
```

You can just do

```
return true;
```

since you don't care about the rest of the array; you already found a matching pair.

Although this doesn't improve the asymptotic runtime complexity, it will speed up your code by terminating early.

2. Sort the array beforehand, then compare adjacent elements:

We can use `Arrays.sort(duplicateArray);` to sort the numbers in ascending order, in only `O(n log n)` time. Now, we guarantee that equal elements are going to be next to each other, meaning that we can find the answer in `O(n)` time afterwards.

The code looks something like this (after you have received input):

```
Arrays.sort(duplicateArray);
for (int i = 1; i < duplicateArray.length; i++) {
  if (duplicateArray[i] == duplicateArray[i - 1]) {
    return true;
  }
}
return false;
```

This reduces your runtime complexity to `O(n log n)`

3. Use a `HashSet`:

`HashSet`s have a `.contains()` method that runs in expected `O(1)` time. Therefore, if we add each number already traversed into a `HashSet`, we can check for equality in constant time. Traversing the array takes, therefore, `O(n)` time, so we can improve the `O(n log n)` solution.

The code would look like this (again after input):

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < duplicateArray.length; i++) {
  if (set.contains(duplicateArray[i])) {
    return true;
  }
  set.add(duplicateArray[i]);
}
return false;
```

The only issue with this is that a `HashSet` will take extra space.

Comment: Thanks for your help